# How to get format-string for data of a ctypes-pointer

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, python-c-api

Given a ctypes-pointer, for example `double**`:

```
import ctypes
data=(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)*4)()   #  results in [NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL]
```

is it possible to obtain a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html#format-strings), which describes the memory layout of the `data`?

Right now, I create a memoryview to get this information, which feels somewhat silly:

```
view=memoryview(data)
print(view.format)   # prints: &<d
```

Is there a more direct way with less overhead? Maybe through using the C-API?

---

One could fill `data` with meaningful values, if this is of any help:

```
import ctypes
data=(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)*2)(
             (ctypes.c_double*2)(1.0,2.0), 
             (ctypes.c_double*1)(3.0))  

#  results in [ 
#               ptr0 -> [1,2],
#               ptr1 -> [3]
#             ]   
print(data[1][0])  #  prints 3.0
```

Comment: How would the format string look for the current example? Cause what *memoryview* returns doesn't seem right.

Comment: @ChrisFati ctypes seems to add `&` for pointer (not sure it is a standard way of doing it - at least it is not mentioned in the official description) so I would interpret this string as "contains pointers to little-endian  double", which is ok at least for my purposes. I don't think it is completely wrong, because memoryview sees it as one-dimensional array of shape `(4,)`

Comment: This might be a typo or me misreading the code , but `double**` or `double*`?

Comment: @DavidW  `data` corresponds to `double**`. In the example above all elements of `data` are `NULL`, but I don't think it is important to have properly initialized (i.e. not `NULL`) elements in `double**`.

Comment: @ead thanks for clarifying. It was me misreading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if there is nothing fundamentally better than `memoryview(data).format`. However, one could speed-up this a little bit by using C-API.

The format-string (which extends the struct format-string-syntax as described [in PEP3118](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3118/#additions-to-the-struct-string-syntax)) is calculated recursively and is stored in the [`format`-member of the `StgDictObject`-object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Modules/_ctypes/ctypes.h#L212), which can be found in the [`tp_dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dict)-field of
 ctypes-arrays/pointers:

```
typedef struct {
    PyDictObject dict;          /* first part identical to PyDictObject */
    ...
    /* pep3118 fields, pointers neeed PyMem_Free */
    char *format;
    int ndim;
    Py_ssize_t *shape;
    ...
} StgDictObject;
```

This `format`-field is accessed only during the recursive calculation and when [a buffer is exported](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L2613) - that is how `memoryview` gets this info:

```
static int PyCData_NewGetBuffer(PyObject *myself, Py_buffer *view, int flags)
{
    ...
    /* use default format character if not set */
    view->format = dict->format ? dict->format : "B";
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Now we could use C-API to populate a buffer (without creating the actual `memoryview`), here implemented in Python:

```
%%cython

from cpython cimport buffer

def get_format_via_buffer(obj):
    cdef buffer.Py_buffer view
    buffer.PyObject_GetBuffer(obj, &view, buffer.PyBUF_FORMAT|buffer.PyBUF_ANY_CONTIGUOUS)
    cdef bytes format = view.format
    buffer.PyBuffer_Release(&view)
    return format
```

This version is about 3 times faster than via `memoryview`:

```
import ctypes
c=(ctypes.c_int*3)()

%timeit get_format_via_buffer(c)   #  295 ns ± 10.3 
%timeit memoryview(c).format       #  936 ns ± 7.43 ns
```

On my machine, there are about 160 ns overhead of calling a `def`-function and about `50` ms for creating a bytes-object.

---

Even if it doesn't make much sense to optimize it further due to the unavoidable overhead, there is still at least theoretical interest of how it could be speed up.

If one really wants to shave off also the cost of filling out the Py_buffer-struct, than there is no clean way: ctypes-module isn't part of Python-C-API (it is not in the include-directory), so the way forward is to repeat [the solution Cython uses with the `array.array`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/adeb5a8647e3d1a9eceaf946378b1eebdd8f8533/Cython/Includes/cpython/array.pxd#L57), i.e. hardcoding the memory layout of the object (which makes this solution brittle because [the memory-layout of `StgDictObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Modules/_ctypes/ctypes.h#L185) can get out of sync).

Here with Cython and without error-checking:

```
%%cython -a  
from cpython cimport PyObject

# emulate memory-layout (i.e. copy definitions from ctypes.h)
cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <Python.h>

    typedef struct _ffi_type
    {
      size_t size;
      unsigned short mem[2];
      struct _ffi_type **elements;
    } ffi_type;

    typedef struct {
        PyDictObject dict;          /* first part identical to PyDictObject */

        Py_ssize_t size[3];            /* number of bytes,alignment requirements,number of fields */
        ffi_type ffi_type_pointer;
        PyObject *proto;            /* Only for Pointer/ArrayObject */
        void *setfunc[3];          

        /* Following fields only used by PyCFuncPtrType_Type instances */
        PyObject *argtypes[4];       
        int flags;                  /* calling convention and such */

        /* pep3118 fields, pointers neeed PyMem_Free */
        char *format;
        int ndim;

    } StgDictObject;
    """

    ctypedef struct StgDictObject:
        char *format


def get_format_via_hack(obj):
    cdef PyObject *p =<PyObject *>obj
    cdef StgDictObject *dict = <StgDictObject *>(p.ob_type.tp_dict)
    return dict.format
```

And it is as fast as it gets:

```
%timeit get_format_via_hack(c) # 243 ns ± 14.5 ns
```